# EKF Localization when robot is in parallel with a landmark.

Tags: localization, ekf

I'm facing a real weird problem with EKF Localization. The filer gives me wrong error every time the robot is in parallel with a landmark. I've debugged the code many times but failed to solve the problem however I found out where is exactly the problem occurs. The following picture shows the scenario. The robot moves in a circular motion. There are four landmarks. I have indicted in the picture where the filer gives me wrong angle for the estimated state.  As you see, when the robot is in parallel with all landmarks, I got a wrong angle for the estimated robot's pose.

[image]

This is another picture shows how the estimated angle is wrong where the red circle is the estimated robot's pose and the blue one is the actual robot's pose.

[image]

I did also track the problem numerically. What I found out is that the estimated measurement of landmark # 4 is in the opposite direction of the actual measurement of landmark # 4.

```
i = 1 <---- landmark 1 <200,0>

est_robot =
    6.4545
   21.1119
    0.1246

Zobs =
  194.9271
   -0.2208
    1.0000

Zpre =
  194.6936
   -0.2333
    1.0000

real_robot =
    6.2069
   20.9946
    0.1188

Mubar =
    6.2844
   21.7029
    0.1201

i = 2 <---- landmark 2 <200,200>

est_robot =
    6.2844
   21.7029
    0.1201

Zobs =
  263.8102
    0.5982
    2.0000

Zpre =
  263.2785
    0.6239
    2.0000

real_robot =
    6.2069
   20.9946
    0.1188

est_robot =
    6.2901
   21.0100
    0.0155

i = 3 <---- landmark 3 <-200,200>
est_robot =
    6.2901
   21.0100
    0.0155

Zobs =
  273.0734
    2.2991
    3.0000

Zpre =
  273.1173
    2.4114
    3.0000

real_robot =
    6.2069
   20.9946
    0.1188

est_robot =
    6.2840
   21.0462
    0.0259

i = 4 <---- landmark 4 <-200,0>

est_robot =
    6.2840
   21.0462
    0.0259

Zobs =
  207.2696
    3.1272 <--- the actual measurement of landmark 4
    4.0000

Zpre =
  207.3548
   -3.0658  <--- this is the problem. (it should be 3.0658)
    4.0000

real_robot =
    6.2069
   20.9946
    0.1188

est_robot =
    6.0210
   20.8238
   -0.5621
```

and this is how I computed the angles.

For the actual measurements,

```
Zobs = [          sqrt((map(i,1) - real_robot(1))^2 + (map(i,2) - real_robot(2))^2)        ;
            atan2(map(i,2) - real_robot(2), map(i,1) - real_robot(1)) - real_robot(3);
                                                                     i];


     % add Gaussian noise 
     Zobs(1) = Zobs(1) + sigma_r*randn();
     Zobs(2) = Zobs(2) + sigma_phi*randn();
     Zobs(3) = i;
 Zobs(2) = mod(Zobs(2), 2*pi);

 if (Zobs(2) > pi) % was positive
    Zobs(2) = Zobs(2) - 2*pi;
 elseif (Zobs(2) <= -pi) % was negative
    Zobs(2) = Zobs(2) + 2*pi;
 end
```

For the predicted measurements

```
q    = (map(i,1) - est_robot(1))^2 + (map(i, 2) - est_robot(2))^2;
    Zpre = [                                                             sqrt(q);
            atan2(map(i,2) - est_robot(2), map(i,1) - est_robot(1)) - est_robot(3);
                                                                              i];

     if (Zpre(2) > pi) % was positive
        Zpre(2) = Zpre(2) - 2*pi;
     elseif (Zpre(2) <= -pi) % was negative
        Zpre(2) = Zpre(2) + 2*pi;
     end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you did not consider the fact that angles are not just real numbers but cyclic ($+ \pi = - \pi$).

> What I found out is that the estimated measurement of landmark # 4 is in the opposite direction of the actual measurement of landmark # 4.

No. The two angles $3.1272$ and $-3.0658$ are rather close and thus these numbers look perfectly fine. The angle difference is $0.09 \equiv 5.17^{\circ}$.

When computing the difference between two angles, you need to make sure the results lie in $[-\pi, +\pi]$ (e.g. as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320986/easy-way-to-keeping-angles-between-179-and-180-degrees)).

Comment: ,I've wrapped the difference, so the angle falls in `[pi,-p]`. I've implemented the entire project in OpenGL and I'm facing same problem. I've wrapped the difference in `[0,2pi]` but I'm getting same problem.

Comment: Well sorry, there is not much to say without more information. Again: Zpre and Zobs above seem fine, your bug is most likely in the code using Zpre and Zobs, which you did not paste.

Comment: I'm using an algorithm that is stated in Probabilistic Robotics book.